# How to retrieve only the contents of the element when using .load on a specific element?

Tags: jquery, ajax

For example, when I do something like this:

```
$('#foo').load(window.location + ' #foo');
```

One would expect the code mentioned supra to reload the contents of the div with an id of `foo`. But no.

But what it actually gives me, if the content of `foo` is:

```
<div id="foo">
  Foofoo
</div>
```

It will give me:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="foo"><!-- Retrieved from the other page, don't want this -->
    Foofoo
  </div><!-- Don't want this either -->
</div>
```

But I just want the contents of the div `foo`. I don't want to add any child elements, so I was just wondering if it was possible to change the configuration to only load the contents, or another way if possible.

Comment: what's with the downvote? did I not explain something clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is `.html()`.

```
$('#foo').load($('#foo').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Then try like this:

```
my_text = $('#foo').text();
$('#foo').load(window.location + my_text);
```